# Scala: why remove is deprecated in favor of filterNot?

Tags: list, scala, immutability, deprecated

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) remove (_ < 2)
<console>:8: warning: method remove in class List is deprecated: use `filterNot'
 instead
       List(1, 2, 3) remove (_ < 2)
                     ^
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3)
```

I don't understand why this is deprecated. Being immutable it should be clear that `remove` would return a new list. In [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) you can find only:

> Deprecated: use filterNot' instead

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because the method `remove` wasn't coherent - for some collections it did a mutable in-place removal, whereas for immutable collections it created a new version. Methods with in-place (bulk) modifications should only be available for mutable collections.